# How to run/execute a script saved from a subprocess in python?

Tags: python, subprocess, databricks

I am using Databricks and making a connection with Shell Scripts to my github Repo. I am trying to mimic the same folders/files on the repo onto my Databricks so that it is dynamic as possible. I am taking each Script/Data from the Github repo and pulling that into my Databricks notebook and saving each as a variable. My question is once I have this file/data saved to a variable how can I execute the python script?

Currently my code looks something like this:

```
%sh git clone github.com/some-repo.git
cd folder/file
import subprocess as sp
some_file = sp.getoutput('cat ./some-script.py;)

print(some_file)
>>> def hell()
>>>    print("hello world!")
```

Also if there is a better way to do this please feel free to recommend.
Thank you

Comment: @Alexander but how do I run that command in the databricks environment?

Comment: Not sure I get the question but see if this helps...1. Github is a supported git provider, so you could basically import the notebooks, then see if it is possible to invoke them. [supported_git_providers](https://docs.databricks.com/repos/index.html#supported-git-providers) 2. I am not sure you could exchange variables between the %sh cell and a %py...you could write output if it is small to an environmental variable and access it in %python cell. Alternatively write the output to a file in dbfs and use the same in the %py cell

Comment: @rainingdistros not sure I follow here. I have the entire script/data already saved to a global variable, and so if I go and print I get back the entire script. But how can I run that script if I have it contained inside a global variable?

Comment: What I had meant was that you have the option to connect to your github repo directly. Anyways can we assume it is python code ? if it is a `.py` code you could import and run as a notebook... Alternatively since you use the %sh cell already...python should already be accessible from there...you could follow the earlier mentioned suggestion...But I am not sure if it is recommended to run like this...

Comment: @rainingdistros I ended up saving as global variables, then running exec() function on them which then allowed me access to their functions. At that point I can just call them directly into my code.